# Extract an ID with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am writing a program that gets lines of input in the following format:

Firstname, Lastname, ID number, contact info

I want to use regex to just grab the ID number which is formatted like A######## where # can be any number.

I have googled and am having trouble understanding VB's regex patterns, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no such thing as "VB's regex". Both VB.NET and C# uses the same [.NET regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax:

> In the .NET Framework, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5 regular expressions and adds some additional features such as right-to-left matching.

Nevertheless, your Regex should be:

```
A\d{8}
```

Which means: Match `A`, then match any digit (`\d`) exactly eight times.

Practical VB.NET usage:

```
Dim input As String = "Firstname, Lastname, A12345678, contact info"
Dim id As String = Regex.Match(input, "A\d{8}").Value
```

Comment: Awesome, this did it and was easy to understand. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
\bA\d+\b
```

In context:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\bA\d+\b")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match("Firstname, Lastname, A123456, Other stuff...")
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/pB0pR5